# "My pyjamas are all wet." Does the word "all" refer to the word "wet" or to the word "pyjamas"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

While someone is putting water into a bowl for their pet, the pet accidentally knocks over the bowl of water and the person says to his pet:

****Watch out! My pyjamas are all wet.****

The ****"all"**** in the sentence confuses me. I think that the word **"all"** belongs to **"pyjamas"** meaning **"all of the pyjamas"**, but then it occurred to me that  may be **"all"** can also mean to show the degree of **"wetness".**

So I can't be a 100% sure whether **"all"** emphasizes the **"wet"** or **"pyjamas."** So, shortly is the word **"all** used here to mean;

1-**All of my pyjamas** are wet.

2-My pyjamas are **completely wet**.

Comment: _All wet_ means _thoroughly soaked_, but in this kind of context it's an exaggeration (like saying "I'm starving" when you are ready for a meal).

Comment: "All of my pyjamas" would mean all the pairs of pyjamas that you own.  So that doesn't make much sense.  Your 2nd interpretation is the correct one.  Your pyjamas are completely wet, thoroughly wet, etc.

Comment: It's potentially ambiguous, but in this context it almost certainly means "wet through" or "completely soaked". But "Ruminants are all herbivores" means "all ruminants are herbivores" (I guess "all herbivore" might mean 100% herbivorous, but it would be odd to interpret it that way.)

Comment: If someone said. "I'd like to play football today but my sports clothes are all wet", that may well mean they're waiting for their laundry to dry because they have nothing dry to wear.

Comment: @StuartF, thans for the good example. So, by saying "....may well mean... do you mean the sentence "I'd like to play football today but my sports clothes are all wet" can have 2 meanings and we can not know which one it would be without a context: 1- "All of my sports clothes ..........." 2- "My sports clothes are completely wet."

Comment: Furthermore, in the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, there may be the type of exaggeration that @KateBunting describes. When something is affected in some way, to a degree that is (subjectively) concerning to the speaker, they may say e.g. 'You can't wear that shirt, it's all stained!', and I might reply to my wife, 'It only has a little spot of gravy, dear'.

Answer (score 1):

"All" is frequently used as an exaggerating or emphasizing figure of speech in many contexts, not only for being wet.

- If I dribble a little water, my shirt gets wet; but if I spill the whole glass, my shirt is *all* wet (even though most of it is still dry).
- If one sees a child after a few years, the child is *all* grown up (even though they are only 10 years old).
- When things go very wrong, they are *all* messed up (even though it's mostly still okay).